# QCalendarWidget day names don't fit

Tags: c++, qt

User of my application has this strange problem that `QCalendarWidget` doesn't render day names in header properly. You can see it on this screenshot:

[image]

Problem is I cannot reproduce this. Does anyone have idea what could be the cause?
Qt version is 5.3.0.

I don't want to blindly increase width of every calendar widget in the application.

Comment: A higher resolution screenshot would be better

Comment: @luliu: I know, but this is what I got from the user. You still can see the problem.

Comment: I think it is a problem with `QCalendarWidget` on `KDE`, more specifically the `KDE` `QStyle`... but I'm afraid it's hard to impossible to fix a bug on a machine that doesn't reproduce it...

Answer (score -1):

qcalendarwidget trabaja con el tamaño de la fuente del elemento

QAbstractItemView

para redimencionar la tabla de tabla de los dias. Entonces...dabo el ancho del widget, se puede hacer un loop para ver cual es el tamaño de letra que corresponde a ese ancho y luego resize:

```
    //ancho objetivo
int calendarWidth = dateDialog_width*.4;
//altura minima necesaria para satisfacer el ancho objetivo
int calendarHight;

int daysFontSize=0;

QSize size;
//voy probando el font size hasta pasarme del ancho objetivo
do
{
    daysFontSize++;
    calendar->setStyleSheet(QString("QCalendarWidget QAbstractItemView:enabled{font-size:%1px;}").arg(daysFontSize));
    size = calendar->minimumSizeHint();
}
while(size.width()<calendarWidth);

//ancho final
calendarWidth = size.width();
//alto final sin botones
calendarHight = size.height();

//porcion del widget que ocupan los botones(en %)
int buttonsHeightPercent = 25;
//pixels del widget que ocupan los botones
int buttonsHeight = calendarHight*buttonsHeightPercent/(100-buttonsHeightPercent);

//agrego la altura de los botones a la altura minima
calendarHight+=buttonsHeight;
//resize
this->calendar->setFixedWidth(calendarWidth);
this->calendar->setFixedHeight(calendarHight);
```

Saludos! "el conocimiento pertenece al mundo"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a english speaking site so please translate your answer to english or it will be removed.